# simple jquery image slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to create a jquery slide show. Each slide have its own info div which is shown here in a short way, containing title only.
But, something is wrong. Only first slide is running, and not completely right.

**HTML**

```
<div id='wrapslider'>
<div id='sliderins'>

<div class='slideimgwrap'>
<img class='slideimg' src='images/001.jpg' alt='img'>
<div class='slideinfo'>
<div class='slidetitle'>TITLE 01</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class='slideimgwrap'>
<img class='slideimg' src='images/002.jpg' alt='img'>
<div class='slideinfo'>
<div class='slidetitle'>TITLE 02</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class='slideimgwrap'>
<img class='slideimg' src='images/003.jpg' alt='img'>
<div class='slideinfo'>
<div class='slidetitle'>TITLE 03</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapslider{
    float:left;
    width:57%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#sliderins{
    width:100%;
}
.slideimgwrap{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    left:0; top:0;
    background:green;
}
.slideimg{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.slideinfo{
    position:absolute;
    left:0; bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.6;
    padding:14px;
    color:#fff;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var w1 = $('#wrapslider').width();
var h1 = (w1 / 16) * 9;
$('#wrapslider, #sliderins, .slideimgwrap').css('height', h1);

function goleft(){
$('#sliderins :last-child').animate({'left': '-' + w1}, 1500, append);
};

function append(){
    $("#sliderins :last-child").prependTo("#sliderins").css('left', 0);
};

var interval = setInterval(goleft, 5000);

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bonaca/uf6u2ng2/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the jQuery selector "#sliderins :last-child" hoping to select the last child of of #sliderins.  Which sounds reasonable but what you're actually doing is selecting any element anywhere within #sliderins which is the last child of its parent.

If you change this to "#sliderins > :last-child" (in two places), your code works.  The ">" means that you are only selecting immediate children of #sliderins (no grandchildren etc.)

Another selector that would work to get the current slide would be ".slideimgwrap:last-child" - i.e. any element on the page with class "slideimagwrap" which is the last child of its parents.

So, you were very nearly there.  Well done!

One minor glitch: your .slideinfo divs push out to the right of their container, because they have the same width but they also have padding (which gets added to the width, depending on what "box sizing" you're using.  Here is an explanation:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Other notes:  javascript is very forgiving and tries to guess when a string is actually a number, but constructing a negative value using the string `"-"` is a bit weird and unnecessary.  To get negative w1, just use `0 - w1`

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot for your explanation.